# RepresenterError: ('cannot represent an object', <roboflow.core.dataset.Dataset object at 0x7f27813d1ed0>)

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, roboflow

I am using a roboflow dataset to train a yolov8m model. It keeps throwing errors. The latest one is

RepresenterError: ('cannot represent an object', <roboflow.core.dataset.Dataset object at 0x7f27813d1ed0>)

please help[screenshot of what the error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWmGq.png)

I don't know what to try. It takes forever for the jupyter notebook I'm running to start working. The usage is low yet it takes forever for things to run.

Edit:
Here is the code:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
#import yolo; use endings n,s,m,l,x in order of small to large,fast to slow, inaccurate to accurate
model = YOLO('yolov8m.yaml')
#run model in the train mode using the data imported above, set epochs, set which device: 0=gpu0 cpu=cpu
model.train(data=project.version(5).download("yolov8"), epochs=1, device=0)
```

Comment: add code and error as text in your question

Comment: added the code. can't add error cause i'm rerunning right now to see if it fixes itself

Answer (score 0):

@Jay Fisher that YOLO train syntax looks strange, and the error suggests the YAML parser is having trouble finding your dataset.

Typically, one might `dataset = version().download` and pass the `dataset.location` into the training command

Comment: Trying that right now. The syntax is based off of what I could glean from the yolov8 documentation. Not really an engineer. I have no idea what I'm actually doing I'm just trying to follow the logic of the code.

Comment: For reference the youtube tutorial provided by roboflow did say to use: `data={data.location}/data.yaml` but it wouldn't run

Answer (score 0):

In my specific case the answer seems to have been setting data = to the actual file path for the yaml file. Thanks peopl